# Terraform: Resolving Conflicting Configuration Arguments

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I have a resource that is attempting to create an autoscaling policy for a sagemaker endpoint on AWS. There are two configuration arguments (1) `customized_metric_specification` and (2) `predefined_metric_specification`. You would only need to specify one of those configuration options. I attempt to create the autoscaling policy with a `customized_metric_specification` but I run into the following error:

```
│ The given value is not suitable for var.target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration declared at
│ variables.tf:128,1-56: element 0: attribute "predefined_metric_specification" is required.
```

I am expecting to be able to switch freely between `customized_metric_specification` and `predefined_metric_specification` depending on the variable I set when creating this resource.

example.tfvars.json

```
{
"target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration": [{
    "scale_in_cooldown": 600,
    "scale_out_cooldown": 300,
    "target_value": 5,
    "disable_scale_in": false,
    "customized_metric_specification": [{
      "dimensions": [{"name": "EndpointName", "value": "ghostwriter-endpoint"}],
      "metric_name": "ApproximateBacklogSizePerInstance",
      "namespace": "AWS/SageMaker",
      "statistic": "Average"
    }]
  }]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "sagemaker_policy" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  name               = "${var.model_name}-Invocations-ScalingPolicy"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target[0].resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target[0].scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target[0].service_namespace

  dynamic "target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration" {
    for_each = var.target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration
    content {
      target_value       = target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value["target_value"]
      disable_scale_in   = lookup(target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value, "disable_scale_in", null)
      scale_in_cooldown  = lookup(target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value, "scale_in_cooldown", null)
      scale_out_cooldown = lookup(target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value, "scale_out_cooldown", null)
      dynamic "customized_metric_specification" {
        for_each = lookup(target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value, "customized_metric_specification", [])
        content {
          metric_name = customized_metric_specification.value["metric_name"]
          namespace   = customized_metric_specification.value["namespace"]
          statistic   = customized_metric_specification.value["statistic"]
          unit        = lookup(customized_metric_specification.value, "unit", null)

          dynamic "dimensions" {
            for_each = lookup(customized_metric_specification.value, "dimensions", [])
            content {
              name  = dimensions.value["name"]
              value = dimensions.value["value"]
            }
          }
        }
      }

      dynamic "predefined_metric_specification" {
        for_each = lookup(target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.value, "predefined_metric_specification", [])
        content {
          predefined_metric_type = predefined_metric_specification.value["predefined_metric_type"]
          resource_label         = lookup(predefined_metric_specification.value, "resource_label", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration" {
  type = list(object({
    target_value       = number
    disable_scale_in   = string
    scale_in_cooldown  = string
    scale_out_cooldown = string
    customized_metric_specification = list(object({
      metric_name = string
      namespace   = string
      statistic   = string
      unit        = string
      dimensions  = list(map(string))
    }))
    predefined_metric_specification = list(map(string))
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to add at least an empty value for the `predifined_metric_specification` since you have it defined in your variable. However, not sure how `for_each` will handle that when `predifined_metric_specification` is empty.

Comment: But doesn't using the lookup make `predefined_metric_specification` default to `[]` when it can't find `predefined_metric_specification` as a key

Comment: Yes, but your variable definition is requiring that you have `predifined_metric_specification`

Comment: I'm getting this error after adding it as an empty list in the vars: `│ The given value is not suitable for var.target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration declared at
│ variables.tf:128,1-56: list of object required.`

Comment: Well, it's a list of map of strings, so you probably need `[{}]`, something like that.

Comment: Oh it's working now but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Also getting this error `Error: creating Application Auto Scaling Policy (ghostwriter-model-Invocations-ScalingPolicy): ValidationException: PredefinedMetricSpecification or CustomizedMetricSpecification must be set for target tracking scaling.` even though I specified "TargetTrackingScaling"

Comment: I don't think the target tracking block can be dynamic when `TargetTrackingScaling` is defined in the `policy_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Terraform v1.2 and earlier, declaring some attributes as part of an object type means that the value given by the caller must include *at least* those attributes in order to match the object type.

That means that if you declare that variable then the caller will need to provide some value for it, which in the case of a list might be the empty list `[]`.

In the forthcoming Terraform v1.3 release it will become possible to declare an attribute as optional, which means that it'll automatically be set to `null` if not specified, and to optionally specify some other default value to use when it's `null`:

```
# NOTE: Requires Terraform v1.3 or later

variable "target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration" {
  type = list(object({
    target_value       = number
    disable_scale_in   = string
    scale_in_cooldown  = string
    scale_out_cooldown = string
    customized_metric_specification = optional(list(object({
      metric_name = string
      namespace   = string
      statistic   = string
      unit        = string
      dimensions  = list(map(string))
    })), [])
    predefined_metric_specification = optional(list(map(string)), [])
  }))
  default = []

  validation {
    condition = len(var.target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.customized_metric_specification) == 0 || len(var.target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration.predefined_metric_specification) == 0)
    error_message = "Only one of either customized_metric_specification or predefined_metric_specification may be set."
  }
}
```

The extra `optional` annotations on `customized_metric_specification` and `predefined_metric_specification` tell Terraform to allow that attribute to be missing in the caller's value. The second argument to `optional` specifies a default value to use when the attribute isn't set, which I set to `[]` in both cases in the above example.

I also included a bonus example of a `validation` block which will raise an error if a caller tries to provide values for both of those attributes. That's not important to what you asked so you can delete that part if you don't need it, but you implied in your question that callers should use only one of these two so I included it for completeness.

If you would be willing to tolerate having to explicitly set `[]` values for these variables for now in Terraform v1.2, you can then adopt the optional attributes feature once v1.3 has been released and you've upgraded to it.